# Building kernel module: `.ko` not built

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to package a driver. However, when I compile the driver I don't get the output file `CorXtiumCLMX4k.ko` as expected, while the `Makefile` does contain the lines:

```
obj-m := CorXtiumCLMX4k.o
CorXtiumCLMX4k-objs := $(GDRV_OBJS) $(TARGETLIB)
```

(Btw any idea what this `-objs` is for? In the kernel documentation they mention the prefix `-y`… but I also tried it without success)

The compilation does not give any error at that step… just no `.ko` file is produced:

```
salsera_xtium> make: Entering directory '/build/va8hwnknyg6cgzqydl3gm64j8z0vyq2i-source/DALSA/src/xtium/xtium_cl_mx4/driver/kernel/linux'
salsera_xtium> make -C /nix/store/n862ppa5sy8bmnhs801cskcisd6z7fd0-linux-5.4.225-dev/lib/modules/5.4.225/build M=/build/va8hwnknyg6cgzqydl3gm64j8z0vyq2i-source/DALSA/src/xtium/xtium_cl_mx4/driver/kernel/linux IROOT=/build/va8hwnknyg6cgzqydl3gm64j8z0vyq2i-source/DALSA/src/xtium/xtium_cl_mx4/driver/kernel/linux/../../../../.. modules
salsera_xtium> make[1]: Entering directory '/nix/store/n862ppa5sy8bmnhs801cskcisd6z7fd0-linux-5.4.225-dev/lib/modules/5.4.225/build'
salsera_xtium>   CC [M]  /build/va8hwnknyg6cgzqydl3gm64j8z0vyq2i-source/DALSA/src/xtium/xtium_cl_mx4/driver/kernel/linux/GDrv_Linux.o
salsera_xtium>   CC [M]  /build/va8hwnknyg6cgzqydl3gm64j8z0vyq2i-source/DALSA/src/xtium/xtium_cl_mx4/driver/kernel/linux/GDrv_LinuxUtil.o
salsera_xtium>   CC [M]  /build/va8hwnknyg6cgzqydl3gm64j8z0vyq2i-source/DALSA/src/xtium/xtium_cl_mx4/driver/kernel/linux/GDrv_Util.o
salsera_xtium>   CC [M]  /build/va8hwnknyg6cgzqydl3gm64j8z0vyq2i-source/DALSA/src/xtium/xtium_cl_mx4/driver/kernel/linux/memmanag.o
salsera_xtium> make[1]: Leaving directory '/nix/store/n862ppa5sy8bmnhs801cskcisd6z7fd0-linux-5.4.225-dev/lib/modules/5.4.225/build'
salsera_xtium> make: Leaving directory '/build/va8hwnknyg6cgzqydl3gm64j8z0vyq2i-source/DALSA/src/xtium/xtium_cl_mx4/driver/kernel/linux'
salsera_xtium> cp: cannot stat '/build/va8hwnknyg6cgzqydl3gm64j8z0vyq2i-source/DALSA/src/xtium/xtium_cl_mx4/driver/kernel/linux/CorXtiumCLMX4k.ko': No such file or directory
```

(note that `make` takes `/nix/…/lib` instead of `/lib` because I'm using Nix so I patched the path accordingly… also I do compile before other libraries that are not shown in this log, see below)

Any idea what could go wrong? I tried to compile with kernel 5.4 (supposed to be supported according to the doc…) and a more recent kernel, none of them work.

### Debug informations

If it can be of any help, here is the list of files in the current folder before the compilation starts:

```
copysources  corenv.h  CorXtiumCLMX4k26_x86_64_a  gdrv.h  GDrv_kernel.h  GDrv_KernelThread.h  GDrv_Linux.c  GDrv_LinuxUtil.c  GDrv_LinuxUtil.h  GDrv_OS.h  GDrv_Util.c  Makefile  sdrv.h  sources
```

At the end, I have:

```
copysources  cormgrlibk.c               gdrv.h         GDrv_KernelThread.h  GDrv_LinuxUtil.c  GDrv_OS.h    Makefile    Module.symvers  serialk.c
corenv.h     CorXtiumCLMX4k26_x86_64_a  GDrv_kernel.h  GDrv_Linux.c         GDrv_LinuxUtil.h  GDrv_Util.c  memmanag.c  sdrv.h          sources
```

The file `CorXtiumCLMX4k26_x86_64_a` seems to be some sort of static binary blob:

```
$ file CorXtiumCLMX4k26_x86_64_a
CorXtiumCLMX4k26_x86_64_a: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), with debug_info, not stripped
$ ldd CorXtiumCLMX4k26_x86_64_a
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `./CorXtiumCLMX4k26_x86_64_a'
        not a dynamic executable
```

(note that I also tried to rename it as `CorXtiumCLMX4k.o_shipped` with `'TARGETLIB = CorXtiumCLMX4k.o'` without success)

Note that latter in the build process (yeah, it continues even after errors), I also get an error:

```
salsera_xtium> /nix/store/039g378vc3pc3dvi9dzdlrd0i4q93qwf-binutils-2.39/bin/ld: warning: /build/va8hwnknyg6cgzqydl3gm64j8z0vyq2i-source/DALSA/Xtium-CL_MX4/lib/libXtiumCLMX4L_1_0_a has a section extending past end of file
salsera_xtium> /nix/store/039g378vc3pc3dvi9dzdlrd0i4q93qwf-binutils-2.39/bin/ld: error: /build/va8hwnknyg6cgzqydl3gm64j8z0vyq2i-source/DALSA/Xtium-CL_MX4/lib/libXtiumCLMX4L_1_0_a: ELF section name out of range
```

but I'm not sure if this error is because I'm missing some compilation flags like `pic`, if the file is just bad, or if it's just that I first need to compile the `.ko` file properly…

the Makefile looks like:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# MAKEFILE
#                   Copyright(C) Teledyne DALSA Inc 2015
#                       All rights reserved.
#
# Description:
#       Makefile for distributed version of the CorXtiumCLMX4 kernel module for Linux
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Determine the kernel version being compiled for.
CORKERNEL_MAJOR:=$(shell uname -r | cut -d '.' -f 1)
CORKERNEL_MINOR:=$(shell uname -r | cut -d '.' -f 2)

#
# Kernel version-specific dependencies
# (mainly needed for 2.4 kernel support).
#
ifeq ($(CORKERNEL_MAJOR), 2)
   ifeq ($(CORKERNEL_MINOR), 6)
      # 2.6 kernel
      TARGET_OPTIONS = -DHOSTPC -DPOSIX_HOSTPC -DNEW_CXM_INTERFACE -DEXPORT_SYMTAB
      #TARGET_OPTIONS = -DHOSTPC -DPOSIX_HOSTPC -DNEW_CXM_INTERFACE -DEXPORT_SYMTAB -DDEBUG_PRINT
      SAPSRCROOT := $(IROOT)/sapera
   else
      # Not 2.6 kernel - not supported (PCIe hardware).
      $(error $(shell echo "Kernel version must be 2.6 or higher to support PCIe hardware"))
   endif
else ifeq ($(CORKERNEL_MAJOR), 3)
    # 2.6 (or higher kernel)
    TARGET_OPTIONS = -DHOSTPC -DPOSIX_HOSTPC -DNEW_CXM_INTERFACE -DEXPORT_SYMTAB
    #TARGET_OPTIONS = -DHOSTPC -DPOSIX_HOSTPC -DNEW_CXM_INTERFACE -DEXPORT_SYMTAB -DDEBUG_PRINT
    SAPSRCROOT := $(IROOT)/sapera
endif

#
# API Version control information to be embedded.
#
ifndef CORARCH
  CORARCH := $(shell uname -m | sed -e s/i.86/i386/ -e s/x86_64/x86_64/ )
endif

TARGETNAME = CorXtiumCLMX4k
TARGET = $(TARGETNAME).ko
ifeq  ($(CORARCH), x86_64)
    TARGETLIB = $(TARGETNAME)26_x86_64_a
    CORARCH_OPTIONS= -Dx86_64
else
    TARGETLIB = $(TARGETNAME)26_i386_a
    CORARCH_OPTIONS= -D__i386__ 
endif

#
# Include Path for the kernel module.
#
I_CORSERIALCOMMON= $(SAPSRCROOT)/driver/corserial/linux/common
CORSERIALDEV= $(SAPSRCROOT)/driver/corserial/linux/kernel
CORMGRK= $(SAPSRCROOT)/driver/cormanager/kernel
XCELERA_HS_PX8_INC= $(IROOT)/xtium/xtium_cl_mx4/include
CURDIR = $(IROOT)/xtium/xtium_cl_mx4/driver/kernel/linux

INC_COMMON_PATH = -I$(CURDIR) -I$(KERNEL_INCLUDEDIR) -I$(CURDIR) -I$(SAPSRCROOT)/include \
    -I$(XCELERA_HS_PX8_INC) -I$(CORMGRK) -I$(I_CORSERIALCOMMON) -I$(CORSERIALDEV)

DISTINSTALLDIR=$(IROOT)/../Xtium-CL_MX4/bin
RUNNINGKERNEL=$(shell uname -r)
INSTALLDIR= /lib/modules/$(RUNNINGKERNEL)/misc

#
# Source Path for the kernel module.
#

#
# Object definitions: Specific files for this library.
# GDrv objects.
GDRV_OBJS = GDrv_Linux.o  \
   GDrv_LinuxUtil.o  \
   GDrv_Util.o \
   memmanag.o \
   cormgrlibk.o \
   serialk.o

# 
# 2.6 kernel build section
#
INC_PATH = -I$(CURDIR) $(INC_COMMON_PATH)

CFLAGS_MODULE += $(INC_PATH) $(TARGET_OPTIONS) $(CORKERNEL_CONFIG_OPTIONS) \
                    $(CORARCH_OPTIONS)
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-parentheses -Wno-missing-braces -Wno-unknown-pragmas \
                -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label

#
# As of kernel 2.6.28 (and later) - versioned module symbol dependencies need to be specified
# explicitly - using absolute paths - to the Module.symvers files for the modules whose
# symbols we depend on.
# (Actually broken in an early 2.6.28 but later fixed).
#
# Prior to 2.6.28 - the kernel build system and module loader would resolve all symbols automatically
#
CORKVER := $(shell uname -r | cut -d '.' -f 3)
CORKTEMP := 28
COMPAREKVER := $(shell echo ${CORKVER}\>=${CORKTEMP} | bc )
ifeq ($(COMPAREKVER),1)
    KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS= $(CORMGRK)/Module.symvers $(CORSERIALDEV)/Module.symvers
else
    $(shell cat $(CORMGRK)/Module.symvers > $(CURDIR)/Module.symvers)  
    $(shell cat $(CORSERIALDEV)/Module.symvers >> $(CURDIR)/Module.symvers)
endif

# 
# 2.6 kernel build section
#
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)

obj-m := CorXtiumCLMX4k.o

CorXtiumCLMX4k-objs := $(GDRV_OBJS) $(TARGETLIB)

#
# Perform any specific kernel configuration difference checks.
#
CORKERNEL_INCLUDEDIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/include

ifeq ($(shell $(SAPSRCROOT)/corcfgtest.sh remap_pfn_range $(CORKERNEL_INCLUDEDIR)),1)
  CORKERNEL_CONFIG_OPTIONS += -DUSE_REMAP_PFN_RANGE
endif

else

KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD  := $(shell pwd)
RES := $(shell ./copysources)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) IROOT=$(PWD)/../../../../.. modules  
endif

   
all: $(TARGET)

clean:
    -$(RM) $(OBJS) $(GDRV_OBJS) $(TARGET)

distclean:
    -$(RM) $(OBJS) $(GDRV_OBJS)

install: all
    cp $(TARGET) $(INSTALLDIR)

distinstall: all
    cp $(TARGET) $(DISTINSTALLDIR)
```

(note that I also tried to turn `else ifeq ($(CORKERNEL_MAJOR), 3)` in `else` since kernel 5 is bigger than kernel 3… still no success).

If you want the full compilation log (including the sub libraries), see [here](https://pastebin.com/2g2GZ89n).

Comment: According to the full log, the other 2 kernel modules are successfully created. Probably, some settings in your Makefile conflicts with the ones in the kernel build system. Note, that your `Makefile` is processed **twice**: once when you enter `make` in the terminal, and the second - when `$(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) IROOT=$(PWD)/../../../../.. modules` is processed. Since 2.6.32 (or even early) the kernel build system is able to use `Kbuild` file at the second step. So you could split your `Makefile` into two files and make sure that `Kbuild` is "clean".

Comment: @Tsyvarev ok thanks a lot! I got access to an update of the drivers so I will try it out and let you know, otherwise I will try the split you mention. Can Kbuild be any makefile-like command or only a few specific commands like `obj-j`?

Comment: Kernel build system interprets `Kbuild` file as any other Makefile, so this file could contain any command suitable for a regular Makefile. So you could use any variables assignment in it. (In `Kbuild` file you could also create rules, but it is unlikely that you will need them there.) BTW, the lines with `obj-m` are regular assignments to Makefile's variables. What special in them is how these variable are interpreted by the kernel build system.

Comment: Thanks! So we got access to a more recent versior, problem solved! Thanks!